# Populating a WPF Listbox with a subset of items from a Dictionary<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a dictionary of `<String, MyThingyClass>` containing a few hundred entries. Now I want to display a subset of these in a WPF Listbox.  How do I do it (preferably in code)?

There are plenty of examples, tutorials etc on how to bind a whole dictionary (Systems.Collection) to a Listbox, but I haven't found any just binding a subset (selected by either key, or a field in the value-class).

I realize that a simple solution is to make a Dictionary that contains a subset and then bind this subset-dictionary to the Listbox. But I wonder if there is a way without creating the subset-dictionary.

Comment: You may look into [How to: Filter Data in a View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx).

Comment: Filters Yes - great idea!  This is a solution I like and that works and is easily extendable. Thanks! If I could, I'd mark is as accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a [`CollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) of your source collection and set the [`Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter.aspx) property.

See [How to: Filter Data in a View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: The third link has gone stale.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create it. you can create a read only property that returns subset of dictionary and bind it in xaml.

Or.

You can hide the items in xaml by some condition in trigger.